# OpenVPN + obfsproxy + obfs3 on Windows?

Tags: windows, socks, openvpn, obfsproxy

I'm in a country where obfsproxy using obfs2 is blocked, however obfs3 is still undetected. I use obfsproxy to route my OpenVPN tunnel through it in socks mode. However although I've managed to setup a server running obfsproxy with obfs3, I cannot get obfsproxy running in windows as it appears that [the latest version built with python and Twisted only implements a socks4 listener](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9221).

I can't find any information on whether there is an older version of obfsproxy for windows that isn't built with Twister and which does implement socks5. Does anyone have obfsproxy working with obfs3 on Windows?

Answer (score 3):

The old version of obfsproxy written in C is mostly deprecated, and it is expected that no further development work on it will be done.  The only legitimate use of it these days is as part of orbot (though I'm trying to kill it there as well).

That said, as of obfsproxy 0.2.7 (The Python/Twisted version), it no longer uses SOCKS4 and instead uses SOCKS5.  It apparently works with OpenVPN (Someone was testing earlier versions of the code with OpenVPN/ScrambleSuit) as long as care is taken to work around the fact that the OpenVPN SOCKS client has [a bug](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2014-March/006427.html).

Since obfs3 does not use the SOCKS5 username/password fields for anything, as long as a non-0 length SOCKS username/password are set in the OpenVPN config, things should work, though I have not tested that.

Comment: How can I set SOCKS username/password?